# Validate string using Regex in C# failed to validate backslash or double-quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `[^0-9a-zA-Z]+` regular expression for removing special character into a string.

But i suffer a problem when my string contains `"` or `\`, this regular expression failed to validate the string.

My C# code is(convert all special character into `-`) -

```
Regex.Replace("MyString", @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "-");
```

but when I pass a string which contains `"` or `\` , this code gives

for `"` - Newline in constant

for `\` - Unrecognized escape sequence

Can any one help me to recover this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape a `"` and a `\` in a string in C#:

```
Regex.Replace("Slash: \\   Quote: \"  ", @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "-");
```

Read more about [escaping characters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma).